# Rails 4 + Solr: Show search result from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have search method in my controller:

```
def search
  @search = Sunspot.search [Post, Siri] do
    fulltext params[:q]
  end
  @posts = @search.results
end
```

Then i have this in my view:

```
- @posts.each do |p|
  %h5= p.title
```

My question is how to show separately in view if @posts from Post model & if @posts from Siri model.

The reason that i want it seperately is because there is some attr are not exists in Post model but exists in Siri model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in class level you can use is_a? to check if the record belongs to which class:

```
- if p.is_a? Post
    // here will be from post model
- elsif p.is_a? Siri
    // here will be from siri model
```

if in atrributes level you can use respond_to? from ruby which is when the object has this property will return true otherwise will be false:

```
- if p.respond_to?(:title)
  %h5=p.title
```